# how to assign variables to an array to unknown length

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables

I've created an empty array with the name pattern and now I am reading a file that generates strings and each string I want to be saved in a variable p. I want the pattern to be displayed on the MATLAB command window. The line assigned to P should be stored in array pattern.

```
pattern=[]
while ~isnan(l)
        p=fgetl(fp);
pattern=(pattern,p[])
end
```

Can you help, I think I am doing it wrong to assign pattern. Because it wouldn't get the result

```
pattern = [];
while(~feof(fid))
    l = fgetl(fid);
    idx = regexp(l, '^information$');
    if size(idx,1)>0
        l = fgetl(fid); 
        while ~isnan(l)
            p = fgetl(fid);
        end 
    end
end
```

The above is the code

Comment: Please provide a [functioning example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can best answer your question. For variable length strings I would advise using a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Also, concatenating arrays in every iteration of a loop is highly inefficient, consider [preallocating](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/resizing-and-reshaping-matrices.html#f1-88760) the cell array for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [cells](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) for this, thus the correct type of brackets is `{}`, not `[]`. When the entire text is saved in a cell array, you can display it using a combination of [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/disp.html).

Something like this should work:

```
fid = fopen('textfile.txt');

p = fgetl(fid);
pattern = {p}
while ischar(p)
    p = fgetl(fid);
    pattern = [pattern; {p}];
end

fclose(fid);
cellfun(@disp, pattern)
```

Comment: It says variable pattern appears to change size on every loop iteration. Consider p reallocating for speed

Comment: Minor comment (even though this solution is awesome).  What about using `celldisp` for displaying cells?

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi - That is expected.  The size of the cell array is changing at each iteration.  What you are asking can't be done with pre-allocation.

Comment: @rayryeng, I don't think celldisp works well for this as the result will be: pattern{1} = *(linebreak)* function why(n) *(linebreak)* pattern{2}  = *(linebreak)* etc. Thanks though =)

Comment: @RobertP. - Oh well I tried!  You're welcome :) +1 btw.

Comment: @rayryeng Depending on the format of the files being read you can count the number of lines in the file to preallocate the array. While it could produce a larger array, clearing empty cells in one call is still more efficient than increasing the array size at every iteration. See this [MATLAB Central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235126) for trivial perl (for windows) & unix implementations that are both quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

if your strings have different length, then you should save them in a cell array.

```
%// create empty cell array
pattern=cell(0) 

while ~isnan(l)
    p=fgetl(fp);

    %// save in cell array
    pattern{end+1} = p

    %// show in command window
    disp(p) 
end
```

now you can access your first pattern with pattern{1} and your second with pattern{2}...